# creating slack modals using / commands not working

Tags: python, flask, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Hi i have been learning to create modals in slack using python flask. Can anybody help me with opening a model, basic enough using a /command.
Thankyou !

```
#@app.route("/raise_issue", methods=\["POST"\])

def open_modal():
    trigger_id = request.form\['trigger_id'\]

    client.views_open(trigger_id=trigger_id, view={
    "type": "modal",
    'callback_id': 'first_view',
    
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "First View"
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit"
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel"
    },
    'blocks': []
    }   )
    return '', 200
```

Comment: Can someone help me with any git link of any slack app which opens a model when a slack command is written. Please help me

Comment: [This](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open/code) might help...